# xtics label with conditions using gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, conditional-statements, labeling

I am interested in labeling the xtics with strings from a column in a file.
The file is written in the following manner:

```
Index Name Status Value
1 Ver1 with 0.3
2 Ver1 without 0.25
3 Ver2 with 0.35
4 Ver3 with 0.27
```

The datas shall be plotted with a conditioned plot

```
plot file u (strcol(3) eq "with"?$1:1/0):($4) w p pt 7 notitle
```

The xtics shall be labeled with the data contained in column(2). If all values are used this can be done by `xticlabel(2)`. But I only want to use the filtered data to get a plot like:

```
|
|     x      x     x
|     
----------------------------
    ver1   ver2   ver3
```

The questions is: How can I label the xtics using only the filtered values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could impose the same condition in `xticlabel` as well, i.e., to use column 2 if required or pass an undefined value instead:

```
plot 'file.dat' u \
  (strcol(3) eq "with"?$1:1/0):4:xticlabel((strcol(3) eq "with")?strcol(2):1/0) \
  w p pt 7 notitle
```

Comment: Very well. Thanks a lot!